# I uploaded photos to my computer, and deleted them off of my camera. Things got weird.

Tags: shotwell, photo, photorec

The photos I want are in Shotwells "missing photos."  I can see their thumbnails there.  I am running a photorec recovery job and after many hours, I still can't seem to find them (although still looking).  Where could they possibly be?

Comment: How did you upload the photos?

Comment: Through shotwell.  Originally to my regular Pictures drive then when I ran out of space, I had to route it to my separate hard drive.  I suspect that was part of the problem.

Comment: running `testdisk` the sister to `photorec` took me 24 hours (with a sleep in between` to recover a 500 GB hard drive with Windows and Ubuntu partitions. Give it some time and post a new question after you've exhausted all data recovery attempts.

Comment: But I've already used photorec.  Can I delete all the files that I pulled up through photorec and still run testdisk?  I thought after writing to the hard disk, you can't recover anymore?  Or is deleting not the same as writing?